# Can SharePoint Hosted Excel Files Use ODBC Connections Without Requiring User Installation?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, excel-services, external-data

I'm looking to share an Excel file on SharePoint that connects to a Cloudera Impala database via ODBC. Locally, after installing the Impala Cloudera ODBC driver and providing the database credentials, I can successfully load data into the file.

However, when sharing this file on SharePoint, I want users to be able to open it and view the data without needing to install the ODBC driver or enter database credentials. I attempted to use the Excel web version on SharePoint, but it appears to not support ODBC connections.

While I understand that setting up a web service or API as an intermediary is a viable solution, I'm curious if there's a way to accomplish this directly within Excel and SharePoint. Is there a built-in feature or configuration that would allow me to share an Excel file with ODBC connections that doesn't require user installation or manual credential entry?